# Get matches from string Powershell

Tags: regex, parsing, powershell

I want to collect the matches to a regex in a specific string, and put them into an array.

This is a simplification of my code so far.

```
$myString = <p>a bunch of html</p> <a href="example.com/number1?ID=2014-89463">go</a>

$myMatches  = $myString -match "\d{4}-\d{5}"
Write-Host $myMatches
```

`$myMatches` is returning the whole string, but what I want, is for `$myMatches` to return as `2014-89463` (and the rest of any matches, be there more).

Also, `$myString` is actually an array of strings, each similar to the one listed above.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
[regex]::Matches([string]$mystring,'(\d{4}-\d{5})') |
foreach {$_.groups[1].value}
```

Casting `$mystring` to `[string]` makes it all one long string, with a space separating each element. Then the `[regex]::Matches()` static method returns all of the matches found in the string. The match objects returned will have a Group object for each captured group, with the `.value` property being the captured value. The `foreach` loop just iterates through all the matches, and spits out the value of capture group 1.

Comment: It seemed to work.  Could you explain why this works?  I'm new to Powershell.

Comment: Casting $mystring to [string] makes it all one long string, with a space separating each element. Then the [regex]::Matches static method returns all of the matches found in the string. The match objects returned will have a Group object for each captured group, with the .value property being the captured value.  The foreach just iterates through all the matches, and spits out the value of capture group 1.